# How do I Set the Shadow around TextView

Tags: android, textview, shadow

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="225dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/left"
            android:background="@anim/chatitemshaodow"
            android:fontFamily="calibri"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:textColor="#636363"
            android:textSize="17dp" />
```

This is my `TextView` controls and I want set the shadow around `TextView`.  I am able to set the Showdown on text in `TextView` but I am unable to set shadow round on `TextView`.

I want to set textview shadow like given Screen in android. [image]

Comment: How looks @anim/chatitemshaodow ? The easiest way how do the frame shadow is via 9-patch graphic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a new drawable resource file. I named mine two_sided_border.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- This is the line -->
<item>
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@color/black" />
    </shape>
</item>
<!-- This is the main color -->
<item android:bottom="2dp" android:right="2dp">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@color/green" />
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Then use this as the background for your textview.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/t"
    android:background="@drawable/two_sided_border"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"/>
```

Your colors and dimensions (padding, text size) can be tweaked to suit.

Two great links:

[how to make stroke for 3 sides for a shape in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558619/how-to-make-stroke-for-3-sides-for-a-shape-in-android)

And borrowed some code from here:

[Open-sided Android stroke?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422120/open-sided-android-stroke)

ps the other answer provided by Basil Miller gives good way to set shadow for the actual text itself.

[image: textview]

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you'd consider using android:shadowColor, android:shadowDx, android:shadowDy, android:shadowRadius; alternatively setShadowLayer() ?

**There is the style:**

```
<style name="Text">
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">4px</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">4px</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffffff</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    <item name="android:shadowColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDx">1</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDy">1</item>
    <item name="android:shadowRadius">1</item>
  </style>
```

**Method 1:**

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/text"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       style="@style/Text"
       android:gravity="center" />
```

**Method 2:**

```
TextView text= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
infoTextView.setTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(),  
       R.style.Text);
```

Comment: i want set shadow on side of textview not  On text

Comment: You can use 9 patch editor and set it to background.

Answer (score 0):

This was work for me

android:shadowRadius="3"
        android:shadowDy="-4"