# How to make stroke in one edge of button?

Tags: android, kotlin

I how can I add stroke only on 2 edges?
I have some tries, but no result.
[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558619/how-to-make-stroke-for-3-sides-for-a-shape-in-android/51180438

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was just to add 4 view items. Just create <View..> and constraint them to button.