# Have bottom border for TableLayout which is used as row in ListView

Tags: android

According to [Open-sided Android stroke?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422120/open-sided-android-stroke), there are basically 2 ways to implement borders for TableLayout.

**Use Stroke**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#00ffffff"/>
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#ffffff"/>
</shape>
```

[image]

However, this is not something which I want, as I only want bottom border. Hence, I try another alternative.

**Use 2 layers**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- This is the line -->
<item>
      <shape>
            <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
      </shape>
</item>
<!-- This is the main color -->
<item android:bottom="1dp">
     <shape>
           <solid android:color="#000000" />
     </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

[image]

However, during list view selection, the `TableRow` will not be highlighted with `ListView` selection color, as its background already take over by **"#000000"** layer.

Is there any better way I can have bottom border only, yet it will obey `ListView` selection highlight color?

Answer (score 1):

In your shape file use `<solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>` instead `<solid android:color="#00ffffff"/>`