# How to add bottom border to tablelayout cells?

Tags: android, border, tablelayout

I've done a TableLayout and I have to put only the bottom border to each cell... so cannot do a rectangle shape...

Any ideas about how to do it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think this will be usefull.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11633522/have-bottom-border-for-tablelayout-which-is-used-as-row-in-listview

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Have bottom border for TableLayout which is used as row in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11633522/have-bottom-border-for-tablelayout-which-is-used-as-row-in-listview)