# Create an Incomplete Button Stroke

Tags: android, android-xml, android-button, android-resources, android-drawable

**Aim:**  Stroke only the top and bottom.

**What I've tried:**

Below is a copy of my XML.
I've tried following the solution in [This Stack Overflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422120/open-sided-android-stroke).
But my problem is that the  doesn't let me choose the options of cutting off the left and right by 1dp as per the solution.

Any ideas?

**Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape >
            <gradient
                    android:startColor="@color/secondaryButtonStartColorSelected"
                    android:endColor="@color/secondaryButtonEndColorSelected"
                    android:angle="270" />
            <stroke
                    android:width="@dimen/secondary_button_border_size"
                    android:color="@color/secondaryButtonBorderColorSelected" />

        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:state_focused="true" >
        <shape>
            <gradient
                    android:startColor="@color/secondaryButtonStartColorSelected"
                    android:endColor="@color/secondaryButtonEndColorSelected"
                    android:angle="270" />
            <stroke
                    android:width="@dimen/secondary_button_border_size"
                    android:color="@color/secondaryButtonBorderColorSelected"/>

        </shape>
    </item>

</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom `Drawable` to handle this for you, but you'd have to set it in code vs XML. Here's a quick and dirty version:

```
public class HorizontalStrokeDrawable extends Drawable {
    private Paint mPaint = new Paint();
    private int mStrokeWidth;

    public HorizontalStrokeDrawable (int strokeColor, int strokeWidth) {
        mPaint.setColor(strokeColor);
        mStrokeWidth = strokeWidth;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw (Canvas canvas) {
        Rect bounds = getBounds();
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, bounds.right, mStrokeWidth, mPaint);
        canvas.drawRect(0, bounds.bottom - mStrokeWidth, bounds.right, bounds.bottom, mPaint);
    }

    @Override
    public void setAlpha (int alpha) {
        mPaint.setAlpha(alpha);
        invalidateSelf();
    }

    @Override
    public void setColorFilter (ColorFilter cf) {
        mPaint.setColorFilter(cf);
        invalidateSelf();
    }

    @Override
    public int getOpacity () {
        return PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
    }
}
```

Now you can just set it wherever you need it:

```
view.setBackgroundDrawable(new HorizontalStrokeDrawable(myColor, myStrokeWidth));
```