# Setting no border on Android Drawable defined in XML

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I'm trying to define a background drawable in XML that will make the background have a 1dp grey border on the left. The XML I'm using is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#00FFFFFF" />
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#CCCCCC" />
    <padding android:left="1dp" android:top="0dp" android:right="0dp" android:bottom="0dp" />
</shape>
```

In the screenshot below you can see that it's actually putting a 1dp border around the entire view (the "Recent Lessons" area):

[image]

Can someone explain to me what I've done wrong here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9212584/2197087 See here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you may have confused padding and stroke. The 1dp stroke you are adding is the border you see around the shape - not the padding. Try following [these examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422120/open-sided-android-stroke). For more about `LayerList` see the [android docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList) (LayerList section). Basically, it boils down to multiple `drawables` as one.