# Android Shape Custom Rectangle

Tags: android, shapes

I have this to draw a rectangle.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#00000000" />
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#ffffff" android:dashWidth="0dp" android:dashGap="0dp" />
</shape>
```

But I want only 2 horizontal lines on the top and on the bottom. How do we achieve that?

[image: Iwant to achieve no 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got clue from this [Open-sided Android stroke?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422120/open-sided-android-stroke)

It works now.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- This is the line -->
    <item android:top="-1dp" android:right="-1dp" android:left="-1dp">
      <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#ffffff" />
      </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:bottom="-1dp" android:right="-1dp" android:left="-1dp">
      <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#ffffff" />
      </shape>
    </item>    
</layer-list>
```